# UIActivityViewController chose different text for WhatsApp or Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have the text in activity Items but now it share on WhatsApp or Facebook, this method share for each app the same text.
is it possible to share different text for each app ?

```
- (void)share {
    NSString *text = @"share test";

    NSArray * activityItems = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", text], [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.co"]];
    NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
    NSArray * excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeMessage];

    UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];

    [activityController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
        NSLog(@"The setCompletionWithItemsHandler completed = %i", completed);

        if (completed) {
            NSLog(@"The selected activity was %@", activityType);

            if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]) {
                NSLog(@"Mail sended");
            } else if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
                NSLog(@"Post on twitter, ok!");
            } else if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
                NSLog(@"Post on facebook, ok!");
            } else if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage]) {
                NSLog(@"SMS sended!");
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

But you can use the open App with URL method and pass an parameter to that App.
When using that method you have to use a custom UI and can not use the UIActivityViewController. (As far as i know)

So, it is possible, if you want to have multiple buttons like:
"Share with WhatsApp"
"Share with Facebook"
etc.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: Yes!

There is actually a way to return different content for multiple apps, AFTER choosing them.

You will have to create two UIActivityItemSource, one which will return an UIImage and other which will return a NSObject. This is done to "fool" the system that you will share these objects, but after the user has selected an app, we can actually return something else, like a URL.

```
class SocialActivityItem: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    var img: UIImage?
    var url: URL?

    convenience init(img: UIImage, url: URL) {
        self.init()
        self.img = img
        self.url = url
    }

    // This will be called BEFORE showing the user the apps to share (first step)
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return img!
    }

    // This will be called AFTER the user has selected an app to share (second step)
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> Any? {
        //Instagram
        if activityType?.rawValue == "com.burbn.instagram.shareextension" {
            return img!
        } else {
            return url
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
class TextActivityItem: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    var textToShare: String?

    convenience init(textToShare: String) {
        self.init()
        self.textToShare = textToShare
    }

    // This will be called BEFORE showing the user the apps to share (first step)
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return NSObject()
    }

    // This will be called AFTER the user has selected an app to share (second step)
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> Any? {
      var text = ""
      if activityType?.rawValue == "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension" {
          text = "Sharing on Whatsapp"
      }

      if activityType == UIActivityType.postToFacebook {
          text = "Sharing on Facebook"
      }
      return text.isEmpty ? textToShare : text
    }
}
```

Then, you just need to set everything up:

```
let url = URL(string: "www.google.com")!
let socialProvider = SocialActivityItem(img: img, url: url)
let textProvider = TextActivityItem(textToShare: "Sharing on social media!")
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [socialProvider, textProvider], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, man! It worked like a charm. WhatsApp couldn't handle text & image at the same time (it shared only text). So, for WhatsApp I just returned nil instead of text and it works, now it shares an image and it's great.

Comment: This caused the share sheet to be empty on iOS 13. If you replace `NSObject()` with `""` it works. Thanks!